# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. when Update-Database in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, connection-string, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have successfully created a migration, but no matter what I do, I can't update the database and the problem seems to be in the connection string.

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=LAPTOP-T70EVGQC\\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=MoviesApi;Integrated Security=True;"
    },
    "frontend_url": "http://localhost:3000",
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    }
}
```

`program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnections")));
```

`ApplicationDbContext.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using MoviesApi.Entities;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace MoviesApi
{
    public class ApplicationDBContext: DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDBContext([NotNullAttribute]DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDBContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDBContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDBContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDBContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("your connection string");

            return new ApplicationDBContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

Migration files:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace MoviesApi.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class Initial : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Genres",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Genres", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Genres");
        }
    }
}
```

```
// <auto-generated />
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
using MoviesApi;

#nullable disable

namespace MoviesApi.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDBContext))]
    partial class ApplicationDBContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "7.0.9")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128);

            SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity("MoviesApi.Entities.Genre", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"));

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(50)
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Genres");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to connect to the database. Using the Package Manager Console, I try to apply the migration (by running `Update-Database`), but I get an error

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Database should be updated with a table genres, if I'm not mistaken.

I even get the error just by getting the list of migrations with "get-migration"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `Data Source` to `Server` in the connection string. Also validate that correct startup project is specified when invoking the update command.

Comment: Thank you, but i've already tried a lot of combinations with the connection string. Apparently all of this

Data Source
Server
Address
Addr
Network Address

Are interchangeable.


Could you elaborate on the second suggestion, please? I'm working from the nugget package  manager and i thought console and i thuoght it updated the database without needing to specify anything.

Comment: Then you need to select correct project as start up one in solution explorer. And verify that other appsetting files do not override the connection string.

Comment: Yes, thank you, i posted an answer just before you commented.

Turns out it's almost what you were saying. I was passing "connection string", literally, where i should've written my actual connection string.

Thanks so much for your suggestions. Had i not figured it out by chance your comment would have saved me an afternoon of suffering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i realized it was a dumb mistake.

Turns out that in the DBContext.cs there's this part

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDBContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("your connection string");
```

And that's where i should be passing the connection string. No wonder it didn't recognize it.